Trying to Make a non-linear ODE into a linear one to then Prove Solution
I am attempting this HW problem with the not so pleasant function:
$$
f''-cf-{3f}^2=0
$$
The problem is a "Show that" where the given solution to the ODE is:
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\sech}{sech}
f(x)=-\frac{c}{2}\sech^2(\sqrt c X/2)
$$
I attempted to work from the given solution backwards, eventually reaching the statement:$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\sech}{sech}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tanh}{tanh}
3=7\tanh^2(\sqrt c X/2)-4\sech^2(\sqrt c X/2)
$$
Which is uuhm, incorrect to say the least. I am now trying to solve it directly but am finding it hard to do the very first thing you are supposed to do with a non-linear ODE; making it linear. The problem is the f'' which makes it impossible to use Bernoulli substitutions or any other methods I know or come across online .
Is there a method to make this equation linear, hence solvable, or is my approach not correct? I am slightly suspecting the latter due to the suspicious appearance of sench which I have never really worked with.
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Hint. $f''=f'\frac{df'}{df}$.

@Cesareo I don't understand how am I supposed to work it out by integrating further, increasing the powers of f instead of reducing them or somehow removing the troublesome f^2 term.

Let us solve this ODE.
Instead of $f''-cf-{3f}^2=0$ I will write $y''-cy-3y^2=0$. Here we have $y(x)$. Let us put $y' = p(y)$. Hence $$y'' = \frac{d y'}{dx} = \frac{d p(y)}{dx} = \frac{d p(y)}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx} = p' p.$$
So  $$y''-cy-3y^2=0 \Leftrightarrow p'p - cy-3y^2 = 0 \Leftrightarrow pdp = (3y^2+cy)dy \Leftrightarrow \frac{p^2}2 = y^3 + \frac{cy^2}2 +  \tilde{d},$$
where $\tilde{d}$ is constant. Put $d = 2\tilde{d}$.
We have $$ y' = p = \pm \sqrt{ 2y^3 + cy^2 + 2\tilde{d}}$$
$$ y' = \pm \sqrt{ 2y^3 + cy^2 + d} $$
$$ \frac{dy}{\sqrt{ 2y^3 + cy^2 + d}} = \pm dx.$$
It sufficies to find the integral from L.h.s., denote if by $F(y)$. So we get that that $F(y) = \pm x + const$.
Note that this is second order ODE so there are two arbitrary constants (one of them is $d$).
The original problem is much simplier: it's sufficient just put $f = -\frac{c}{2} sech^2(\sqrt c X/2)$ and check directly that $f''-cf-{3f}^2=0$.

It seems the LHS integral is not solvable neither by me, nor by computer. It says that an elementary solution does not exist for this derivative.

@Crusader It's general solution and it's the way to get linear equation. If we need (as in original problem) partial solution, we may put $c = 0$ or $d=0$ or even $c=d=0$ and get partial solution.
